# onAttach(Activity activity) what is this activity in a fragment inside another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

It sounds me a confusing Question. What is the Activity Object in onAttach method of a fragment which is nested inside a parent Fragment?

I know I can communicate to the parent fragment by using getParentFragment() method.But I  want to know if this activity object in the onAttach returns the FragmentActivity instance or not, so as to have a direct communication (by using interface callback) from a nested fragment to the FragmentActivity.

Sorry for my bad English. I tried my best to convey my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Activity object is your FragmentActivity. Check the docs here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29)

You can also get the activity by using getActivity() anywhere in your fragment (but be aware it only works after onActivityCreated has been called)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the `FragmentActivity` that hosts the `Fragment` (directly or nested in another `Fragment`). There is more information about communicating with the parent `FragmentActivity` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).